# programmatic access to vba from java script does not work

Tags: vba

Currently, we have a report which runs

- User triggers the report
- report is processed and saved in xml format
- When the report is finished, user get the option to download the report
- When user clicks on download, a web service is called.

  1. this web service opens blank excel book
  2. copies macro from a separate xml module (which resides in the server)
  3. Macro processes finished xml report and show it in the sheets

This all works perfectly fine when using Excel 2002 (SP 3).

*Our workstations are planned for upgrade from XP to Windows 7. With Windows 7, comes Excel 2010.*
I tried the whole step in the testing machine provided by infra team.

When testing, we found that macro from xml module was not getting copied in excel 2010.
No errors and no warnings.

I did a bit of searching and found that "Trust access to the VBA project object model" needs to be ticked.
Tried doing it but to no avail.

Let me know if anything is not clear or need more information.

**Edit 1**
This is how JS is opening the excel + adding workbook + adding module:

```
xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
//Add a workbook
xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add;

// This loads the modules into XL from the reporter_modules
var xlMod;
xlMod = xlBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1);
xlMod.CodeModule.AddFromString(xmlModule.childNodes(i).text);
```

Since there is just .xls in Excel 2002, code does not mention the extension while opening excel anywhere. Do you know how can this be achieved?

Thanks,
Meet

Comment: Just in case, For all the MS Product, after you change setting, it only activates after you close the application and activates on the next time.

Comment: @Larry, thanks for the comment. Did that already. Restarted the machine to make sure the check box is still ticked.

Comment: could it be that you have problems with accessing newly created files, as they are normally not in "full access" for everyone? maybe windows7 blocks the access from server.

Comment: @Vogel612: Nope. Newly created report is accessed by excel macro. Here, I am stuck a step before. Java script is able to open the excel but not able to copy the macro module from a different xml file (which never changes)

Comment: @Meet why not copy the existing file with the macro then?

Comment: Are you using .xlsx or .xslm file type? .xlsx won't allow macro modules.

Comment: @Pynner: Please see my edit in the question. Code does not mention the extension when opening the excel. Is there a way to open a new/blank excel workbook with extension?

Comment: I am currently trying to create a .xslm type template and save it under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICEx\XLSTART folder. But need administrative privileges. Will update.

Comment: Update: created the template. but when doing "xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add", it ignores the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the file type on save. Which is in a different section of the code than what you have posted. excel will allow you to add the Vba modules to the .xlsx but will give a warning on save (which your java code is no doubt supressing). I don't know the java syntax but in Vba it is

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\ron.xlsm", fileformat:=52
```

52 is a filetype constant that excel uses. You can see more detail @ http://www.rondebruin.nl/saveas.htm

Comment: No good. Since the report is running in web server. I can't have JS save the excel sheet on client side. Infect, report when running in Office 2002 is also not saved on clients local (he has to save it manually).

Comment: Hmm I think the issue is not related to the file format then. It might be worth trying just to see if that is the issue. I am now a bit more inclined to think it related to Windows 7 security. do you have a XP/Excel 2010 machine that you can try?

Comment: Tried in XP with excel 2010 but same result. Macro is not getting copied :(

Comment: I'll throw out something else to try if possible, can you run the code on the server directly (IE client machine is the server?).

Comment: Well..they have not installed Office in the server..so can not try it.